# Is there Modular 's cycling property?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Find the number of incongruent solution of the congruence $$x^5+10 \equiv 0    \pmod {11^4}$$

this is problem

When I try to solve it, in $\mod 11$, $$x \equiv 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \pmod{11}$$ becomes $$x^2 = 1,4,9,5,3,3,5,9,4,1.$$

It is symmetric with mid is $3$! is there some property of modular like cycle or rotation property ?

I don't want to check every number. Can I stop the check when I have same number?

e.g, in $x^2$ in $\mod11$ , $1,4,9,5,3,3$ (same! stop! .. can I do this ?)

and I want to know the solution of this problem.

Comment: The property you're observing with the squares is that $(-n)^2=n^2$, because $6\equiv -5$, $7\equiv -4$, etc. Fifth powers are different...

Comment: Is that supposed to be a square rather than a fifth power in the original question?

Comment: Oh thanks i see.

Comment: Oh thanks i see. And i want to know the method to solve the original problem. What is answer? I think that the answer is 7 in mod 11^4 using hensel's lifting lemma . I found 7 of x which is true for x^5+10=0 mod11 and f'(r) is not 0(right?) . Therefore all 7 root is lifted uniquely to mod11^4 so the answer is 7 in mod11^4 ?

Comment: I agree that Hensel's Lemma is your friend here. I haven't worked out the details myself, but I will when I have more time.

Comment: thanks. i 've leanred hensel's lemma last week and i 'm trying to be familliar with that